# How to change Eclipse IDE GUI icons?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, icons

Elipse icons are ugly. Fact!

I would like to replace the icons with more flat, monochromatic and minimalist icons, but I can't find documentation on how to change icons from Eclipse's user interface.

How could I do this? It's needed to recompile eclipse?

Comment: For anyone arriving here like me, years after this question was asked ... though not a direct answer but a way to find better icons, have look at the eclipse market place for available themes. darkest-dark-theme has a nice icon set, you can then tailor the IDE colors to suit your preferences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the icons seem to be stored under **\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\684\1.cp\icons** AND in other folders of **\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles**.

You can either change/create them yourself or you can search for icon packs and just replace them, there are plenty of packs out there for example in [deviantart](http://www.deviantart.com/) (there are some awesome free to use ones there!).

Also... never say "Eclipse icons are ugly. Fact!" or else, it kind of sounds rude and discredits the work of the artist that made them, just say that you don't like them.

Comment: Where are this image icons refered? There's some editable configuration file? I would love to use svg files instead bitmaps.

Comment: What means the number named folders? This are fixed names? The same icons will be on the same folder on any version of Eclipse?

Comment: Note: these are temporary locations where Eclipse unpacks the contents of plugin jars when it needs to access files individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icons using this tool. It changes the look and feel including the inline search. Check this -> https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle